# wordpress orderby fallbacks

Tags: php, wordpress, sql-order-by

I'm having some problem making my main query in wordpress with fallback of orderby.

the current code:

```
$query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'order_priority';
$query->query_vars['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
$query->query_vars['order'] = 'ASC';
```

I want to make a fallback of random order to those posts that have certain value of the order_priority.

Comment: Can you even do this in sql?